# Plotting the data using the matplotlib and coloring the group histograms with the same color

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, data-science

I'm trying to plot a graph using matplotlib library. Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [[206.6, 735.4, 427.9, 175.2,384.4],
[487.5, 273.7, 742.6, 159.5,144],
[613.4, 0, 294.9, 0,0]]
X = np.arange(5)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.bar(X + 0.00, data[0], color = 'b', width = 0.25)
ax.bar(X + 0.25, data[1], color = 'g', width = 0.25)
ax.bar(X + 0.50, data[2], color = 'r', width = 0.25)
ax.legend(labels=['Group-1', 'Group-2','Group-3','Group-4','Group-5'])
```

[image]

I want the above graph groups to be of same color. Example, Group-1 histograms should be `Red`, Group-2 histograms should be `Blue`, Group-3 histograms should be `Orange`, etc.. How can I get that using the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would do what I think you're asking for starting from your code. The request seems a little odd to me as you could label the groups of plots on the x-axis so color offers an obvious way of labeling each of the series).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [[206.6, 735.4, 427.9, 175.2,384.4],
[487.5, 273.7, 742.6, 159.5,144],
[613.4, 0, 294.9, 0,0]]
X = np.arange(5)
col_list = ['red','blue','orange','green','cyan']
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
handles = ax.bar(X + 0.00, data[0], color = col_list, width = 0.25)
ax.bar(X + 0.25, data[1], color = col_list, width = 0.25)
ax.bar(X + 0.50, data[2], color = col_list, width = 0.25)
ax.legend(labels=['Group-1','Group-2','Group-3','Group-4', 'Group-5'],
           handles=handles)
plt.show()
```

Gives:

[image: plot]