# How to create a grouped bar plot using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to do something similar to this circular `barplot` but with a regular `barplot`. I want to group each value based on the group I create and label it.

Circular Bar Plot example. Source: python-graph-gallery.com:

[image: Circular Bar Plot example. Source: python-graph-gallery.com]

I've tried to copy the similar code from the website but I can't do that for regular bar plot and my own data from CSV.

Comment: Please create a minimal example with your best-effort code and with some simple test data.

Comment: See e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64731307/plotting-the-data-using-the-matplotlib-and-coloring-the-group-histograms-with-th)